# If $AB=BA$ and $A=P^{-1}DP$ then $B=P^{-1}SP$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that: If $AB=BA$ and $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ is diagonal matrix then $B=P^{-1}SP$ such that $S$ is diagonal matrix.

Comment: Since this is true with $A=P=D=I$, it implies that any matrix $B$ is diagonalizable, which is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to assume that $B$ is at all diagonalizable, as per Harald Hanche-Olsen's comment above. Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalisable, with $A = P^{-1}DP$, then $B$ being diagonalizable as $P^{-1}SP$ means exactly that any eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $B$. You have to be careful with degenerate eigenvalues of $A$ though, since if any eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to a specific eigenvalue has dimension more than $1$, then $P$ might decompose that eigenspace in a way that is incompatible with the eigenvectors of $B$.

An example of this is
$$
A = \left[\matrix{0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1}\right],\quad B=\left[\matrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3}\right]
$$
where the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ has dimension $2$. In this case, we could of course use $P = I$, the identity matrix, but any matrix rotating the $xy$-plane and fixing the $z$-axis, that is, any matrix of the form
$$
P_\theta =\left[\matrix{\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0\\0&0&1}\right] 
$$
would satisfy the conditions above, but most of them do not diagonalize $B$.

But assuming that all entries in $D$ are distinct, and that $B$ is at all diagonalizable, let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $Bv$ also is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, that means that $Bv$ must be parallel to $v$, and therefore that $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$:
$$
A(Bv) = (AB)v = (BA)v = B(Av) = B(\lambda v) = \lambda(Bv)
$$
and therefore any (non-degenerate) eigenvector of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $B$ and they are therefore diagonalisable using the same $P$.

Comment: eigenspace of A corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$  has dimension $ \ge 2$ $Bv$ really do not need parallel to $v$

Comment: @RoadHuman That is why I start my last paragraph by assuming that all entries in $D$ are distinct. If all eigenvalues are distinct, then any two vectors with the same eigenvalue must be parallel.

Comment: there fore, this problem  don't complete ?

Comment: @RoadHuman As you've written your problem in the question, yes, it's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

$A=A_1,B=A_2$ And

It's full solution:

Let $M_j=\ker(A_1-\lambda_jI)$ and $N_j=\ker(A_2-\lambda_jI)$. There fore,

$\mathbb{C}^n=\bigoplus_{j=1}^kM_j=\bigoplus_{j=1}^lN_j$ because all diagonalizable.

We have:
$$M_i=M_i \cap \mathbb{C}=M_i \cap \bigoplus_{j=1}^lN_j=\bigoplus_{j=1}^l(M_i \cap N_j)$$

We will prove that if $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A_1$ then $A_2$ too.

Let $\mathbf{v}$ is any  eigenvector of $A_1$ and such that $\mathbf{v} \in M_i$ under eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ 
We have:

$A_1(A_2\mathbf{v})=A_2(A_1\mathbf{v})=\lambda_i(A_2\mathbf{v})$
 Hence,$A_2\mathbf{v} \in M_i$ But  $M_i=\bigoplus_{j=1}^l(M_i \cap N_j)$ so  $A_2\mathbf{v}$ is in $N_j$ .

Because $\bigoplus_{j=1}^l N_j=\mathbb{C}^n$ so that have a set of base vectors of $A_2$ of $\mathbb{C}$. That is: $\mathbf{v_{11}},\mathbf{v_{12}},\mathbf{v_{13}},...,\mathbf{v_{1i_1}};\mathbf{v_{21}},\mathbf{v_{22}},...,\mathbf{v_{2i_2}};...;\mathbf{v_{j1}},\mathbf{v_{j2}},...,\mathbf{v_{ji_j}};...,\mathbf{v_{l1}},\mathbf{v_{l2}},...,\mathbf{v_{li_l}}$

W.L.O.G

$\mathbf{v}=\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{s=1}^{i_k} \alpha_{ks}\mathbf{v_{ks}}$ (1)

$$\Rightarrow A_2\mathbf{v}=A_2\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{s=1}^{i_k} \alpha_{ks}\mathbf{v_{ks}}=\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{s=1}^{i_k} \lambda_k \alpha_{ks}\mathbf{v_{ks}}$$
But $A_2\mathbf{v} \in N_j$ i.e. $A_2\mathbf{v}=\sum_{s=1}^{i_j} \beta_{js} \mathbf{v_{js}}$ (2)

Hence,

$\sum_{s=1}^{i_j} \beta_{js} \mathbf{v_{js}}=\sum_{k=1}^l\sum_{s=1}^{i_k} \lambda_k \alpha_{ks}\mathbf{v_{ks}}$

$$ \Rightarrow \begin{cases} \alpha_{ts}=0  \ \ \ \ \ \forall t \not=j,s=\overline{1,i_t} \\  \beta_{js}=\lambda_j \alpha_{js} \end{cases}$$

back to (1) :  $\mathbf{v}=\sum_{s=1}^{i_j} \alpha_{js}\mathbf{v_{js}}$.
back to (2) we have: $A_2\mathbf{v}=\sum_{s=1}^{i_j} \lambda_j \alpha_{js} \mathbf{v_{js}}$

Hence, $A_2\mathbf{v}=\lambda_j\mathbf{v}$ i.e. $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A_2$.

Q.E.D